# Content Security Policy: Couldn't parse invalid source chrome-extension - FB script error in Firebug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, fbconnect, facebook-likebox

when i check [my website](http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com) with Firebug, it shows the following error message :

**Content Security Policy: Couldn't parse invalid source chrome-extension: ...**

Then another piece of the warning :

```
...conds();wa=na.getUTCMilliseconds();}na=(pa<=0||pa>=10000?(pa<0?"-":"+")+o(6,pa<0...
```

and it is linked to a FB script : http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js
I have FB Like Box installed. When i delete it, there is no error anymore.
The code which is embed in a WP html widget :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/il.webdesign" data-height="410" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

Is there a way to correct this FB script error ???

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like the error is coming from an installed extension.

So check if you have unwanted extensions and remove them. If the problem still occurs, then disable the remaining extensions one by one to find out the culprit.

Note also the [answer within the  Code Project forum](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/747688/Content-Security-Policy-Couldnt-parse-invalid-sour#answer1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer... however i do not understand why you talk about extensions when i said that the error is coming from the all.js which is on Facebook Connect...
I re-edit my question to complete with the fact that when i delete FB Like Box, there is no more error message... so, the question is "if there is a way to correct this error".

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and fixed it by eliminating malware from spigot on my computer... yes I am one who posted the "answer within Code Project forum" and similar in another post within stackoverflow. Unfortunately a month or so later the same original error and warnings came back for me but just as of yesterday, 4/22/2014 they changed to these 5 warnings, instead:

1. "Content Security Policy: allow directive is deprecated, use the equivalent default-src directive instead
   ...conds();wa=na.getUTCMilliseconds();}na=(pa<=0||pa>=10000?(pa<0?"-":"+")+o(6,pa<0...
   all.js (line 27)"
2. "The X-Content-Security-Policy and X-Content-Security-Report-Only headers will be deprecated in the future. Please use the Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Report-Only headers with CSP spec compliant syntax instead."
3. "Content Security Policy: allow directive is deprecated, use the equivalent default-src directive instead"
4. "The X-Content-Security-Policy and X-Content-Security-Report-Only headers will be deprecated in the future. Please use the Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Report-Only headers with CSP spec compliant syntax instead."
5. "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.

...{href:function(a){return a.getAttribute("href")},type:function(a){return a.getAt...

jquery.min.js (line 3)"

My guess is that the errors/warnings are due to the way the Facebook like button is engineered and how it interacts with Firefox and other browsers. The change in warnings and errors to these new warnings seems to indicate that Facebook and or Mozilla are working on this issue and will hopefully fix it...???

---

`yesterday, 4/29/2014` This was officially classified as a Facebook known bug issue I created and is currently being addressed. Below is text from the FB email to me:

The bug you are subscribed to ["like button works but errors show onload in firebug "Content Security Policy: Failed to parse unrecognized source chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl""](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/729597157070762) has been updated:
Status has changed: Closed → Assigned

Hi All, We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team. This might take some time to fix but we will do our best to keep you updated on the progress of this bug as soon as we can. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comment... yes, i see, the error message has changed. I do not have the same what you have because i do not have FB Like Button, i have FB Like Box but it makes the same kind of problem : "Content Security Policy: Impossible d'analyser la source invalide chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdho..." 
I hope someone will know the solution soon or hopefully FB will correct this sh.t by itself... :)